# What does "function(): any{" mean

Tags: javascript

I saw this snippet [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20151210223742/http://flowtype.org/docs/react-example.html#property-use):

```
render: function(): any {
  var thread = this.state.thread;
  var name = thread ? thread.name : "";
  var messageListItems = this.state.messages.map(getMessageListItem);
  return (
    <div className="message-section">
    <h3 className="message-thread-heading">{name}</h3>
// ...
```

What does the `function(): any{`  part in the first line mean?

Apologies if this has been asked before, but it's really hard to search this, particularly when you don't know what it's called.

Comment: Is this using a framework?

Comment: The snippet is part of reactjs but the particular line is plain javascript (I expect its some ES6 thing). Render is a member of an object

Comment: This isn't Javascript code. It is "flowtype", some sort of pre-processor.

Comment: Perhaps any is it's return / accepted argument type? I'm kinda just looking at flow now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's not a part of JavaScript, it's an extra feature added by [Flow](http://flowtype.org/), a JavaScript preprocessor. [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) also has a similar feature.

Essentially, Flow adds a type-checking feature, and to use it you add type-hinting to symbols. In this case, `: any` is a type hint for the `render` method, meaning the method could return any type.

#### Excerpt from the [type annotations docs](http://flowtype.org/docs/type-annotations.html) for `any`:

> `any` is a special type annotation that represents the universal
> dynamic type. `any` can flow to any other type, and vice-versa. `any`
> is basically the "get out of my way, I know what I am doing"
> annotation. Use it when Flow is getting in your way, but you know your
> program is correct.

---

A fun little side note, there was a proposed feature in the [now-abandoned ES4 draft](http://www.ecmascript.org/es4/spec/overview.pdf) for type hinting that was very similar to this. As far as I know, it was only ever implemented in the ES-derived ActionScript 3.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple and straightforward answer is `function(): any` will return `any type` of data.

It means you can return `string` `boolean` `number` or any type of data you want from that function.